# Split a string with a lot of dividers

Tags: java

i have a issue with programming for android.

i have a string like this:

> [["Km"],["Portagens"],["Refeições - Almoço"],["Refeições -
>   Jantar"],["Refeições - Lanche"],["Estacionamento"],["Estadia
>   Hotel"],["Gasóleo"],["Gasolina"],["Taxi"],["Combóio"],["Avião"],["Viatura
>   de Aluguer"],["Viaturas
>   BIQ"],["Economato"],["Correio"],["Outros"],["Refeições - Pequeno
>   almoço"]]

I want to split this, to save the content into a array, like this:

```
Km
Portagens
Refeições-Almoço
Refeições-Jantar
Refeições-Lanche
Estacionamento
```

.
.
.
.

So the dividers are:

```
1- [
2- ]
3 - "
4 - ,
```

How can i split the string with this chars?

If i use `[\\W]`, i get some blank strings.

Can you help me?

Regards.

Comment: have you tried splitting with `\\W+` ?

Comment: Give this a go [\\w+?], also can you post the code you're using...

Comment: That's no good, it would also split `Refeições - Jantar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
[\[\]\",]{1,}
```

This splits where there are one or more of the 4 characters you mentioned.

```
String[] words = str.split("[\\[\\]\\\",]{1,}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = s.split("\"\\],\\[\"");
```

You will have special handling for the first and last token.

Answer (score 0):

- escape the [ and ] because they're regex chars already
- include the quotes " " either side which aren't captured by \w
- use ? for minimum match - best practice, not strictly necessary here.

Code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]");

String input = "[[\"Km\"],[\"Portagens\"],[\"Refeições - Almoço\"],[\"Refeições - Jantar\"],[\"Refeições - Lanche\"],[\"Estacionamento\"],[\"Estadia Hotel\"],[\"Gasóleo\"],[\"Gasolina\"],[\"Taxi\"],[\"Combóio\"],[\"Avião\"],[\"Viatura de Aluguer\"],[\"Viaturas BIQ\"],[\"Economato\"],[\"Correio\"],[\"Outros\"],[\"Refeições - Pequeno almoço\"]]";

Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
Km
Portagens
Estacionamento
Gasolina
Taxi
Economato
etc.
```

Comment: I think this will miss > 1 token strings (e.g., "Estadia Hotel")

Comment: @KyleRenfro Yep sorry hadn't spotted that, thanks, updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using [StringTokenizer](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/out/target/common/docs/framework/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

```
StringTokenizer st =
                new StringTokenizer("[[\"Km\"],[\"Portagens\"],[\"Refeiçoes - Almoço\"],[\"Refeiçoes - Jantar\"],[\"Refeiçoes - Lanche\"],[\"Estacionamento\"],[\"Estadia Hotel\"],[\"Gasóleo\"],[\"Gasolina\"],[\"Taxi\"],[\"Combóio\"],[\"Aviao\"],[\"Viatura de Aluguer\"],[\"Viaturas BIQ\"],[\"Economato\"],[\"Correio\"],[\"Outros\"],[\"Refeiçoes - Pequeno almoço\"]]", "\",[]");


        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String token = st.nextElement().toString();
            System.out.println("Token = " + token);
        }
```

Note: this has not been tested.